# 1st and last object in array are empty

Tags: php

idk why, but doesn't Mather how long will be the string i get always 1st and last object empty for example:

Example below doesynt mather i found a issue, every numer from 4 to 8 were thansfer in to [], example

```
    $lenght = [4,4,4,4,4];
     $val22= 0;
        foreach ($lenght as $key => $value) {
            $val22 = $val22+$value;
            echo $val22;
        }
// output when i copy: 4 8 12 16 20 what i see: [] [] 12 1[] 20
```

[image]

```
$word1 = 'same char ar';
//outout = [] 4 [];
```

code i use:

```
$mainPass = 'Stack overflow community please help me with it';
 $mainArray = explode(' ',$mainPass);
 function lenght($val){
    $return_value =[];
    foreach ($val as $key => $value) {
        $return_value[]=strlen($value);
    }
    return $return_value;
 } 
 $lenght = lenght($mainArray);
 foreach ($lenght as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
            echo '<br>';
 }
```

everything should work, i check for errors but did not find any...

What kind of stuff my code should do:
Take string in to pieces by space and create array
After that we check each object length
And we echo values...

But 1st and last object are always empty, i got something like that: []

If somebody can help me with it i will be glad.

Comment: Your code works fine [eval](https://3v4l.org/VnCEY)

Comment: Everything works https://3v4l.org/PRpeD

Comment: Ye i know it works... or it should... i find a issue... i dont know why but i got [] instead numbers from 4 to 8... rest numbers were displayd well.. hmmm